# Price divide shows zero

Tags: magento-1.9, php

It always Return 0 only I can't understand

```
<?php $emi = Mage::helper('core')->currency($this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice()),true,false);// 5000?>
<?php $mnth = 12;
echo $emi_value = $emi/$mnth;?>
```

Comment: Check if `$emi` is numeric or not first.

Comment: yes it return 5000 rs

Comment: '5000 rs' is not numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to divide a non-numeric value, and so it is returning the 0.

Try with this code instead :

```
<?php $emi = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice()); ?>
<?php
    $mnth = 12;
    $emi_value = $emi/$mnth;
    echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($emi_value, true, false);
?>
```